# Reading a text file in c++ after taking a file name from user

Tags: c++

I am just trying to take a file name(example: file.txt) from user and reading it out. But getting some error. Can any body please help me out to perform this task successfully. If their is any other way of doing this please let me know. And please check your solution before answering.

```
ifstream myfile;
string myline, filename;

cin >> filename;    // Reading the filename
myfile.open(filename);

if ( myfile.is_open() ) 
{
    while ( myfile ) 
    { 
        getline (myfile, myline);
        cout << myline << " ";
    }
}
```

for example I have a text file `myfile.txt` having content as

```
abc  
def  
fgh
```

So i will be getting the same thing as an output.

input: `myfile.txt`

output :

```
abc  
def   
fgh
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Where in your code does that error happen?

Comment: [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)'

Comment: You should update to a compiler, which supports c++11 standard,  older standards only accept a `const char*` parameter for `open()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked by updating the compiler.

Comment: @ArsalanFiroz Even an older compiler may work, when compiling just add option `-std=c++11` if it is GCC/CLang compiler or option `/std:c++latest` if it is MSVC.

Comment: `while ( myfile ) { getline(...); ... }` should be `while ( getline(...) ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an old compiler then as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143449/reading-a-text-file-in-c-after-taking-a-file-name-from-user#comment123993382_70143449) by @πάνταῥεῖ `.open()` function may have no support for `std::string` filename, then you can use `.open(filename.c_str())` to pass `const char *`. This correction is present in following code.

Also if you have older compiler, still you may solve your issue if you try to specify compiling option `-std=c++11` to GCC/CLang compilers or `/std:c++latest` to MSVC compiler. This also may possibly solve your issue.

Otherwise update you compiler to new one.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143449/reading-a-text-file-in-c-after-taking-a-file-name-from-user/70143777#comment123993732_70143449) by @Someprogrammerdude instead of `while (myfile) { getline(...); ... }` you should use `while (getline(...)) { ... }`. This correction is also present in following code.

In following code I added first block in main() that writes to `myfile.txt`, this is only for testing example for StackOverflow visitors, so that example code is fully self-contained. You should remove this file-writing block, because you already have `myfile.txt` and this block will just overwrite it.

Full corrected code:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/nWxhvW3M1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    {
        ofstream myfile("myfile.txt");
        myfile << "abc\ndef\nfgh";
    }

    ifstream myfile;
    string myline, filename;

    cin >> filename;    // Reading the filename
    myfile.open(filename.c_str());

    if ( myfile.is_open() ) 
    {
        while ( getline (myfile, myline) ) 
        { 
            cout << myline << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc
def
fgh
```